# Flexibility of Yii

Tags: zend-framework, yii, php

I have come across a fair bit of information on CI being a really flexible framework.  Does Yii also allow great flexibility?  And the ability to pick and choose when to use it or your own php?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flexibility is very subjective, so this question is a bit vague.

From my experience I can tell you that Yii is *very very powerful*, but in most cases when you want to go into really advanced territory you have to do things "Yii's way". If you do, you will find that the pieces of the puzzle click together really well and things go smoothly. If you don't (because presumably you haven't realized yet what "Yii's way" is), it's going to give you a hard time.

Comment: Thanks Jon, didn't mean for this to be subjective although it may have come across this way.  You answered it well though with " but in most cases when you want to go into really advanced territory you have to do things "Yii's way"".  That is the info I am looking for.

Comment: I tried CI and Cake and found them confusing and hard to get started quickly. Granted, I hadn't done any MVC then so it was all new. I then found Yii and the "lightweightness" of it was attractive enough for me to invest time learning it. I use it for almost every front-end project I build now. :)

Comment: @TheKeeperoftheCheese: I 've used Yii just once, but I am experienced in PHP and MVC and the project was medium-large so there was a lot of happy hacking. It was a pleasant ride and I 'll certainly use it again.

Comment: Be sure to check out my extension library. Some cool junk in there. It's gotten way to big and unwieldy so I'm in the process of refactoring. Current: http://github.com/Pogostick/ps-yii-extensions and New: http://github.com/Pogostick/yiixl

Comment: I agree with this answer. Yii is good if you do it the "Yii Way". If you try to do it another way, you end up fighting the framework.

Answer (score 4):

I am using YII since 2 years. I use it with combination with Zend AMF and create backend systems for Flash campaigns, create HTML5 webpages, simple pages, different competition pages and and find it usable for every case you need. The main advantage that it is really structured, logical and fast. So because of that I am spending my time on creating application logic, not on setting up environment, setting up all requests, pages, subpages etc., MVC model + ActiveRecord saves my time here.

Answer (score 2):

I have been using Yii for a year now and find it very flexible. You can add your own methods to any model or write components outside models. You need to be familiar with the MVC structure, Object-oriented programming and for writing components, you need to know how to register the component in the config file and how to call it the Yii way.